Cypress - reCaptcha load error: Refused to load the script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive
I am needing to get a reCaptcha token for my site key as part of some data setup steps in a test scenario.
I am using cucumber step definitions, and have the following:
import { load } from 'recaptcha-v3'

Then('retrieve reCaptacha token', function () {
  load('<sitekey>').then((recaptcha) => {
    cy.log(recaptcha.getSiteKey())
    recaptcha
      .execute('submit')
      .then((token) => {
        cy.log(token);
      }).catch((err) => {
        cy.log(err)
      });
  }).catch((err) => {
    cy.log(err)
  })
});

When Cypress invokes this, I see the following error:
Refused to load the script 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=explicit' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

I suspect I am mis-using this somehow inside the Cypress test runner, what do I need to do to get past this?

That looks like straight-up javascript/Typescript there... once you use load() method it's going to inject the script via 
I’m not specifying any headers though, is this recaptacha lib adding them ?

CSP headers can be added in front-end markup, or on server's response.  Not sure why you're having to import/inject the recaptcha while running tests though?  Shouldn't anything you are testing already be in place?

forgive me, I'm not familiar with Cypress, so I may be misunderstanding a lot here...  maybe check here?: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/content-security-policy  (it says by default it will remove the CSP headers, so not sure what's happening here)

I don't think you would add a feature like recaptcha from a test - what are you aiming to do by this?
